# How to automatically load a project when starting Delphi

Tags: delphi, command-line

I want to specify a project to be opened when I launch Delphi(D2010).

Is there a command-line parameter to pass to bds.exe, like the -r option allowing to load a specific Registry Setting, where I could pass the name of the project I want to open when launching bds.exe?

The only options I know of are:

```
-ns  "no splash"      
-np  "no project"   
-hm  "Heap Monitor"  
-attach "attach to process(JIT)"  
-r    "registry root"  
-p    "Personalities"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the path after your command.

```
"{path to rad studio}\bin\bds.exe" -pDelphi "C:\Projects\TestProj\TestProj.dproj"
```

BTW: [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options) is the IDE Command Line Reference.

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty that's what I tried and it did not work... Anyway, I retried after your answer and it was exactly what I wanted! (must have mistyped or goofed with the quotes).  Thanks also for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that instead of launching Delphi, you should just double-click the project file. The OS will start Delphi for you, and Delphi will open the project automatically. Make a shortcut to it on your desktop or in your Start menu for easy access.

In Delphi 7 and earlier, use the DPR file. For later versions, use the DPROJ or BDSPROJ file instead.

Works for project groups, too.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but I need to do it with a parameter. No UI available nor even ShellExecute.